# How can I access the inserted record in a subquery inside of an SQL trigger?

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers, sql-insert

I am creating a database that holds information for tests, test questions, and the questions on each test. I have 3 tables: `problem`, `test`, & `question_list`. `problem` holds the information for a question, `test` holds the information for a test, and `question_list` holds the keys for a test and all the problems it has.

I am trying to create a trigger that will insert a number of `problems` into `question_list` when a `test` is inserted based on the new `test_id`, `problem_count`, and `category`. Here is what I have:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER generate_question_list
AFTER INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO question_list (test_id, problem_id)
     SELECT NEW.test_id, p.problem_id
     FROM problem p 
     WHERE p.category REGEXP NEW.category
     ORDER BY RAND() 
     LIMIT NEW.problem_count;
END #
```

My problem is that it's giving me an error and telling me that it doesn't know what `NEW` is. I assume this is because I am trying to reference `NEW` in the `SELECT` statement. How can I get around this and make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The argument in the `LIMIT` clause does not support an expression.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html says:

> `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using `?` placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

The simplest solution is to declare a local variable:

```
...
BEGIN
     DECLARE v_problem_count INT;
     SET v_problem_count = NEW.problem_count;

     INSERT INTO question_list (test_id, problem_id)
     SELECT NEW.test_id, p.problem_id
     FROM problem p 
     WHERE p.category REGEXP NEW.category
     ORDER BY RAND() 
     LIMIT v_problem_count;
END
```

P.S.: We can't use `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` in MySQL within triggers or functions, because the caller may itself be a prepared statement.